# Display new markers when map bound changed and clear old marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2

when map bound moved by user, make disappear old position markers and display new markers.

For an example you can check this [map](https://www.ikyu.com/ap/srch/UspW11115.aspx?are=140000&asc=01&st=1&lc=1&rc=1&ppc=2). Markers are moving every time bounds updated and clearing the old position markers. I am exactly trying to do this.

### UPDATED 2

what I have done so far is right below. No errors but, still seeing all markers at once..?

```
data(){
     return {
        bounds:{},
        map: {},
        mapName: "map",
        estates: [], 
     }
},
mounted() {
    axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
        this.estates =  response.data
        this.insertMarkers();
    });
    this.initMap();

},
methods: {

            initMap: function() {

        this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(34.652500, 135.506302),
        );

        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            zoom: 8
        };


        let self = this;

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapName), mapOptions);

        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((this.map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {

            self.getMarkers();

        });

        this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds);
    },

    getMarkers: function() {

        let bounds = this.map.getBounds();

        let southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
        let northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
        console.log(southWest);

        axios.get('/ajax', {
            params: {
                fromLat: southWest.lat()-0.01,
                toLat: northEast.lat()-0.01,
                fromLng: southWest.lng()+0.01,
                toLng: northEast.lng()+0.01,
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            this.estates = response.data;
            this.updateMarkers();
        });

    },

    updateMarkers: function() {


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {

            var map = this.map;
            var estates = this.estates;
            let i = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
                this.markers[i].setMap(null);
            }

            this.markers = [];

            for (i = 0; i < estates.length; i++) {

                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(estates[i].lat, estates[i].lng);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    label: {
                        text:
                            estates[i].price.toString().length == 1 ?
                            estates[i].price.toString().replace("1", "未定") :
                            estates[i].price.toString() + "万",
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    icon: '/img/marker.png',
                    url: "/pages/" + estates[i].id,
                });

                this.markers.push(marker);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    window.location.href = this.url;
               });
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: I would do it the other way around... that is: 1) Load the map 2) Get the map bounds 3) Query your database to retrieve only markers within the map bounds 3) On map `bounds_changed` event, remove the markers from the map and start again at point 2)

Comment: Hmm, I think I need answer style of explanation :)) @MrUpsidown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can do it the other way around. Fetch only markers that are visible within the map viewport. You just need to reorganize your code a bit and modify your database query.

You need to pass a minimum and maximum latitude and longitude to your controller so that you can query the DB for markers *between* the given latitudes and longitudes. You can get these by getting your map bounds and extracting southwest and northeast lat/lng.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bounds: {},
      map: {},
      mapName: "map",
      estates: [],
      markers: [] // Added markers array here
    }
  },
  mounted() {

    this.initMap(); // On "mounted" only call initMap
  },
  methods: {

    initMap: function() {

      //giving specific location of japan.
      this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(34.652500, 135.506302),
      );

      var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 5
      };

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapName), mapOptions);

      let self = this;

      var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((this.map), 'idle', function(event) {

        self.getMarkers(); // When map is idle, get markers
      });

      this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds);
    },
    getMarkers: function() {

      // Get current map bounds
      let bounds = this.map.getBounds();
      let southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
      let northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();

      // Send request with min/max latitude and longitude to only fetch markers for that area
      axios.get('/ajax', {
        params: {
          fromLat: southWest.lat(),
          toLat: northEast.lat(),
          fromLng: southWest.lng(),
          toLng: northEast.lng(),
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        this.estates = response.data;
        this.updateMarkers();
      });
    },

    updateMarkers: function() {

      // Remove previous markers
      for (let i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
        this.markers[i].setMap(null);
      }

      // Reset markers array
      this.markers = [];

      // Add current markers
      for (i = 0; i < estates.length; i++) {

        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(estates[i].lat, estates[i].lng);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map: map,
          icon: '/img/marker.png',
          url: "/pages/" + estates[i].id,
        });

        // Push marker to markers array for future removal
        this.markers.push(marker);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your controller, you need to get the parameters you send with the axios request (`fromLat`, `toLat`, etc.)

```
public function ajax() {

  // Here you need to retrieve the parameters sent by the axios request !
  // And set them as $fromLat, $toLat, etc.

  $data = \DB::table('allestates')
  ->where('lat', '>', $fromLat)
  ->where('lat', '<', $toLat)
  ->where('lng', '>', $fromLng)
  ->where('lng', '<', $toLng)
  ->get();

  $response = response()->json($data);
  return $response;
}
```

Untested, but that should work. You need to adapt some parts! Read my comments in the code as well.

**Note:** the `bounds_changed` event is triggered repeatedly when a user drags the map, so this way you are going to send a lot of requests to your database. Instead, you should probably prefer another event such as `idle` or delay the trigger of your ajax call somehow to reduce the number of queries.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but there is a problem in controller I can't fetch the data anymore... seeing this error endpoint https://imgur.com/a/SSJMm4k these vars `$fromLat` causing the problem I guess...

Comment: Did you read the comment I put there? `Here you need to retrieve the parameters sent by the axios request !` Did you adapt your controller code? + the screenshot error you posted has not much to do with the code I posted... it's about a log file that can't be accessed. If you still have an issue update your question with the controller code.

Comment: I updated the controller code. could you check it out. I guess I am doing wrong .. :) Because params are retrieving `null` ? and additionally, inside `initMap` function `this.getMarkers()` pops up with this error in the console Uncaught TypeError: this.getMarkers is not a function

Comment: the Type Error was a typo as `this` in the listener is not a reference to the Vue object. See my update where I used `self` instead. The controller code looks ok to me but I can't do your debugging... Check what lat/lng values are sent to your controller. Check what comes out of your MySQL request, etc.

Comment: it's working, thanks to you really...! But, about idle. the where should I use that event? I wrap the updateMarker function but this time markers are disapparing... also update the question with the new code.

Comment: No, you should **replace** the `bounds_changed` event by `idle`, that would be my suggestion. I'll update my answer.

Comment: oh, I get it! thank you, and I have one last question, sorry for the burden :) actually weird things is happening. Actually my endpoint still giving an error.  I found, why when I  `console.log(southWest);` the bounds `lat` and `lng` returns null https://imgur.com/a/BHydxRQ...  I am seeing markers, but I can't return json data at endpoint, because params are being null... Any idea?

Comment: `lat()` and `lng()` are functions so you won't see the output by just logging `southWest`. You can do `console.log(southWest.lat())` and `console.log(southWest.lng())` if you want to see the values. Same for NorthEast of course. You can tell that from your javascript console (image you posted above) that both lat and lng have a *`f ()`* next to it which means they are functions.

Comment: hm, then why I am endpoint giving an error of null then? actually, from yesterday I am having this error in the console. https://imgur.com/a/C3ASEkh I am a bit confused because I can use geolocation and also map too but having api error too...  is it the reason of end point. By the way thank you so much. I checking this as an answer.

Comment: I can't really answer that. Do you do any other calls to the API than what you shared here? Do you use a valid API key and did you enable billing? etc. I'd suggest you check your Google API Console, the link in the error message, and maybe other parts of your code and ask a separate question if you can't figure out what is going on. What you asked for in this question has been solved IMO.

Answer (score -1):

You need to store old Value and compare with new one you need timeout function to update each time iterval  ex window.setTimeout(insertMarkers,3000)

```
for(var i=0, len=res.length; i<len; i++) {

            //Do we have this marker already?
            if(markerStore.hasOwnProperty(res[i].driver_id)) {
                  markerStore[res[i].id].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng({lat: parseFloat(res[i].lat), lng: parseFloat(res[i].lng)}));
            } else {
                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position:  {lat: parseFloat(res[i].lat), lng: parseFloat(res[i].lng)},
       map:map       
                }); 
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i,id) {
                        return function() {
                            console.log(id)
                        }
                    })(marker, i,id));

                markerStore[res[i].id] = marker;

            }
        }
                markerStore[estate.id] = marker;

            }

    });
```

**UPDATE**

```
mounted() {
.
.
.

this.initMap();
window.setTimeout(this.insertMarkers,3000)

    },
methods: {
.
.
.
insertMarkers: function() {
var marker=[];
var markerStore = {};
    this.estates.forEach((estate, index) => {
 //Do we have this marker already?
            if(markerStore.hasOwnProperty(estate.id)) {
                  markerStore[estate.id].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng({lat: parseFloat(estate.lat), lng: parseFloat(estate.lng)}));
            } else {
                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     icon: '/img/marker.png',
                    position:  {lat: parseFloat(estate.lat), lng: parseFloat(estate.lng)},
                    map:map       
                }); 
                var es_id=estate.id;
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, index,es_id) {
                        return function() {
                            console.log(es_id)
                             window.location.href = "/pages/" + es_id;
                        }
                    })(marker, index,es_id));
                markerStore[estate.id] = marker;
            }

    });
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but if you edit this with using my code I can understand much better... because looks like you write whole bunch of new stuff :)) thank you.

Comment: thank you for the update, I run the code bock but having this error: `ReferenceError: markerStore is not defined` And edit the question code for debug... Am I missing something? Additionally, I added timeout into mounted after initMap is it the right place, because getting error for that... Thank you!

Comment: only add `var markerStore = {};` before `this.estates.forEach((estate, index)`

Comment: Now, I have an error that: Error in mounted hook: `"ReferenceError: insertMarkers is not defined"` thank you for helping me ut on this... really appreciate

Comment: set  `window.setTimeout(this.insertMarkers,3000)`

Comment: You *should*: indent your code properly, explain what you have changed, what it does and how it will solve the question asked. Thanks.

Comment: Now getting marker is not defined error at this line: https://imgur.com/a/H2EXeJu Thank you!

Comment: i updated the code , initialize maker  `var marker=[];`

Comment: okay, there is no error. But no difference. still I can see the all markers and when I move map, markers not disappears and adding new markers... which is like here... https://www.ikyu.com/ap/srch/UspW11115.aspx?are=140000&asc=01&st=1&lc=1&rc=1&ppc=2

Comment: thank you answering back. still same problem. I am seeing all the markers at once, when I move the map, there is no change... but setTime is working I can see re rendering... but it no effect on markers... displaying all at once, not disappear old position markers and display new position markers.

Comment: hmm , check this  [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) maybe you find something useful

Comment: I updated the codes and add new explanation too... I will be really appreciate if you check it out, catch the mistakes... Thank you!

Comment: try `{lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)}`

Comment: I am seeing markers, no problem there... But still having bounds problem. displaying all marker at once...

Comment: well try

 `var place1=  new google.maps.LatLng(47.783209299575965, 149.510235786438)

    var place2=  new google.maps.LatLng(26.13514533283748, 124.28562641143799)
  
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(place1);
    bounds.extend(place2);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);`

Comment: it didn't work. I think the main problem is how to use bounds... in the markers... I am making ne_lat ne_lng but how to use it on locations... I think...